# need some way to convert QCOW2 to OVF or open QCOW2 on WINDOWS

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, qcow2, ovf

is there a way to convert `QCOW2` to `OVF`?
or is there a way to open an `QCOW2` on WINDOWS (**preferably free/open source**)?

the problem is that ubuntu's *virtual machine manager* was used to create the image and now i'd need to use it on windows (xp).

**is there a chance?**
thnx

Comment: what virtualization software were you going to use on Windows? OVF might not be your best destination depending on the answer...

Comment: ended up not doing it, but reinstalling an image in virtualbox from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution I found for the same conversion requirement is to install QEMU on Windows and use the same syntax as for regular qemu-img

```
C:\Program Files\qemu>qemu-img.exe convert -O qcow2 image1.vmdk image1.qcow2
```

Source for downloading the qemu binaries [here](http://qemu.weilnetz.de/w64/) or [here](http://qemu.weilnetz.de/w32/)